# how to render a React-Bootstrap Progress bar from Right to Left?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have to display one progress bar from right to left and another from left to right.I am using "React-Bootstrap" Progress bar to acheive left to right.

How to use the same to get the progress bar from right to left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float the element displaying the progress to the right instead with a bit of custom CSS.

CSS:

```
.progress.right .progress-bar {
  float: right;
}
```

JS example:

```
<ProgressBar className="right" active now={25}/>
```

Rendered:

[image: example of progress bar floated to the right]

---

Here's a live example which lets you play with the progress to show the animation from right-to-left:

- [Live version](https://44524650-react-bootstrap-progress-bar-rtl.surge.sh/)
- [Example source](https://github.com/insin/stackoverflow/tree/master/44524650-react-bootstrap-progress-bar-rtl)